# Load from file cannot be referenced from a static content

Tags: java, class, file-io, static

I don't know what's wrong with my main class. I dont know how to change it to fix it. Computer says: load from file cannot be referenced from static context. If I try to change it, my main class is missing.

```
public class Bsp3_1225814_3 {

    public void static main(String [] args){
        List<Linienzug> lst = new ArrayList<>();

        load_from_file("C:\\Users\\schurzm\\Google Drive\\TU\\2.Semester\\VU_Grundlagen Programmieren\\Projekte_Schurz\\1225814_3\\3_in"); 
        dump_to_file("C:\\Users\\schurzm\\Google Drive\\TU\\2.Semester\\VU_Grundlagen Programmieren\\Projekte_Schurz\\1225814_3\\3_out");
    }

    public void load_from_file(String file) {
        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))).useDelimiter("\\n");
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    String[] in = s.next().split(":");
                    Linienzug l = new Linienzug();
                    for (int i=0; i<(in.length-1); i++){
                        l.add(new Punkt(Integer.parseInt(in[i]),
                        Integer.parseInt(in[i+1])));
                    }
                    this.lst.add(l);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.print("File not found");
            } finally {
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please remove all the unrelated code from your example?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call a method that does not have the `static` keyword when you are in a static method. This is because there is an implicit reference to the `this` pointer which does not exist in a static context.

Comment: You can change load_from_file to be static as well.

Comment: alright, but now he says that in load_from_file, that variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Your whole design needs rework. You should be using the "this" variable in an class which will be instantiated, ie. one where you are going to store data and perform operations. Static methods are for situations when (a) starting a program or (b) performing operations that are context-independent.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot invoke instance methods, from a static context in this way.
You have to create an instance to invoke them.

Fix...

```
Bsp3_1225814_3 bsp3 = new Bsp3_1225814_3();
bsp3.load_from_file("C:\\Users\\schurzm\\Google Drive\\TU\\2.Semester\\VU_Grundlagen Programmieren\\Projekte_Schurz\\1225814_3\\3_in"); 
bsp3.dump_to_file("C:\\Users\\schurzm\\Google Drive\\TU\\2.Semester\\VU_Grundlagen Programmieren\\Projekte_Schurz\\1225814_3\\3_out");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void static main(String [] args){
 Bsp3_1225814_3 myObj = new Bsp3_1225814_3();
 myObj.load_from_file("C:\\Users\\schurzm\\Google Drive\\TU\\2.Semester\\VU_Grundlagen 
 ...
}
```

And declare lst as a member of your class.